# How to handle large json values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I have a large json file which needs to be processed via a javascript library. However whenever I open that webpage chrome seems to break the page and print the last portion of the json.How to handle such a situation?

Comment: what is large? 1mb? 100mb? Are you using file choose to get file? Are you using console.log to display it?

Comment: Does it need to be processed in a browser? Can it be on the server and the results of processing sent to the browser?

Comment: The json is embedded in the javascript file. The file is a result of another program.

Comment: @Adam it needs to be processed in the browser only.

Comment: @juvian it is around 150 KB.

Comment: 150kb is far from a large json file. Show us some code.

Comment: @iroh - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask